# Can we reset For loop counter in VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have an Array say: `VMHArray` = (12,22,34,4) Now have another `Arraylist` object say `ArrayListTaskDetails` holding the data as (12,55,44,4,12,22,21,107,43,22,34) Now the below code I wrote to remove items from the list `ArrayListTaskDetails` which are not present in the `VMHArray`.

***Code***

```
Dim Flag : Flag = true
Dim Counter
For IndexSearch = 0 To ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 step 4

    Counter = 0
    Do while Flag

        If VMHArray(Counter) <> ArrayListTaskDetails (IndexSearch) Then

          ArrayListTaskDetails.RemoveRange IndexSearch, 4
          Flag = False

        End If
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop

Next
```

Now Suppose a match found at `IndexSearch = 0`,so according it would delete the element at locations `0,1,2,3` - quite good. But due to removal and to make the `ArrayList` object contiguous by functionality other elements will be shifted by `4` to left. Now the problem is as `For Loop` already incremented by 4,so it would start from next iteration from `location 4`. Thus now the new element at `0 location` in the array list can never get a chance to test the equality with the `VMHArray` array elements. Can we handle such scenario without loosing the intended operation or anyway if we can set the `For Loop` counter to its immediate position,where the just recent match found and 4 elements removed.?

If any issue to understand the problem,let me know please!

***EDIT*** `Go to` will not work

**CODE(as per @Ankit suggestion)**

```
Option Explicit

Dim Flag : Flag = true
Dim Counter
Dim VMHArray : VMHArray = Array(12,22,34,4) 
Dim ArrayListTaskDetails : Set ArrayListTaskDetails = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(45)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(4)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(22)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(4)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(45)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(20)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(12)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(35)
    ArrayListTaskDetails.Add(34)

    Restart:
For IndexSearch = 0 To ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 step 4

    Counter = 0
    Do while Flag

        If VMHArray(Counter) <> ArrayListTaskDetails (IndexSearch) Then

          ArrayListTaskDetails.RemoveRange IndexSearch, 4
          Goto Restart
          Flag = False

        End If
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop

Next

MsgBox(Join(ArrayListTaskDetails.ToArray()),"$")
```

[image: Error]

Thanks,

Comment: did you try `exit for` writing a `for` or try [this to exit while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271949/exit-a-while-loop-in-vbscripts)

Comment: @bonCodigo If I used `exit for` then how the rest element will be checked?

Comment: Try the code I have given please. To be very frank, sorry I haven't gone through the entire *full novel text*, just looked at your title and the code.

Comment: Just iterate your loop from the last element to the first like `For IndexSearch = ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 To 0 step -4`. This will also circumvent needless looping over elements that are already inspected.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I am getting the below error:`Cannot use paranthesis when calling Sub` Any help why so? from the line `MsgBox(Join(ArrayListTaskDetails.ToArray()),"$")`

Comment: @AutomatedChaos - looping backwards is correct, but your starting position is wrong (should be .Count - 4)

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I agree! you catch a bit bug within the line :)

Comment: @CodeLover You have your parenthesis of your Join statement placed incorrectly, letting the `,"$"` belong to the MsgBox (the second parameter for Join is optional, that is why you don't get an error on that statement). MsgBox needs to be `call`ed if you want to use parenthesis, otherwise get rid of them. Now, the VBScript engine sees `"$"` as the second (optional) parameter for messagebox and is giving you this warning.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner nice find.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Can you help me here with a tips [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119936/i-am-not-able-to-clear-and-reset-the-background-color-of-a-cell#comment19549322_14119936)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ideas to solve the problem:

1. use a dictionary to check for the items to keep
2. loop backwards

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim alSrc : Set alSrc = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim sE
For Each sE In Split("a x x x b x x x c x x x d x x x e x x x f x x x a x x x")
    alSrc.Add sE
Next
WScript.Echo "alSrc:", Join(alSrc.ToArray(), ".")
Dim aKeep   : aKeep       = Split("a d")
WScript.Echo "aKeep:", Join(aKeep, ".")
Dim dicKeep : Set dicKeep = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each sE In aKeep
    dicKeep(sE) = 0
Next
WScript.Echo "dicKeep:", Join(dicKeep.Keys(), ".")
Dim nI
For nI = alSrc.Count - 4 To 0 Step -4
    sE = alSrc(nI)
    If Not dicKeep.Exists(sE) Then
       alSrc.RemoveRange nI, 4
    End If
    WScript.Echo sE, nI, Join(alSrc.ToArray(), ".")
Next
WScript.Echo "alSrc:", Join(alSrc.ToArray(), ".")
```

output:

```
alSrc: a.x.x.x.b.x.x.x.c.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.e.x.x.x.f.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
aKeep: a.d
dicKeep: a.d
a 24 a.x.x.x.b.x.x.x.c.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.e.x.x.x.f.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
f 20 a.x.x.x.b.x.x.x.c.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.e.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
e 16 a.x.x.x.b.x.x.x.c.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
d 12 a.x.x.x.b.x.x.x.c.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
c 8 a.x.x.x.b.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
b 4 a.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
a 0 a.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
alSrc: a.x.x.x.d.x.x.x.a.x.x.x
```

**As to the mystery of .Count - ?:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 - Count 1 - 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 - Idx   0 - 7
A x x x B x x x - Count (8) - Step (4) = Pos to check (4)
                  Count (8) - Step + 1 (5) = Not the pos to check (3)
```

Comment: can you just give me a tips about the Post - [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119936/i-am-not-able-to-clear-and-reset-the-background-color-of-a-cell#comment19549322_14119936) . I tried there but looking a one liner , and I know it possible, Thus asking you to help! please

Comment: why `.Count-4` not `.Count-5`. As Count give us the Total number of elements, and to access that element we used always ArrayList(Count-1). Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!! Love your knowledge!

Comment: Could you just help on my above mentioned post?

Answer (score 0):

Resetting `For loop counter` means you somewhat do not let it `iterate`. You have to be very careful not to run into an `infinite loop`. Frankly not reading your huge text. But looking at your code and title, please do try the following:

```
For IndexSearch = 0 To ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 step 4
    Counter = 0
    Do while Flag
       If VMHArray(Counter) = ArrayListTaskDetails (IndexSearch) Then
          ArrayListTaskDetails.RemoveRange IndexSearch, 4
          Flag = False
          If IndexSearch >= 4 then 
            IndexSearch = IndexSearch - 4 '-- add this to go back to previous index
          End If
       End If
       Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop
Next IndexSearch
```

Comment: what `IndexSearch + 4` does?

Comment: Keep in mind that the loop will still try to iterate to the original `ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1` causing a subscript out of range error for `ArrayListTaskDetails (IndexSearch)`. VBScript does not update to `from` and `to` values during a loop.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Already warned OP about *infinity* ;) and just trying to get him understand what is happening with the code. So OP can set propert error handling, validations..