# Exit a while loop in VBA/VBS

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have an Excel VBA program that loops through each row of data in a data sheet.

My goal is to exit the while loop once boolean `bFound` is set as `True`.

I think my condition "Or bFound=True" might be incorrect.

```
bFound = False
While Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 1) <> "" Or bFound = True

    If Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 11) = Sheets("Data2").Cells(iRow, 1) Then
        bFound = True
    End If

    iRow = iRow + 1
Wend
'exit loop after the boolean=true
```

Comment: Replace the **Or** with an **And**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exit a while loop in VBS/VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271949/exit-a-while-loop-in-vbs-vba)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `Do ... Loop` and `Exit Do`

```
bFound = False
Do While Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""
    bFound = Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 11) = Sheets("Data2").Cells(iRow, 1)
    If bFound Then Exit Do
    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: @bigbryan, note that outside the loop `iRow` points to the row where exit condition has been matched, but not to the next row as it intended in your code.

Answer (score 6):

Flip the logic around, I expect this will work for you:

```
bFound = False
While Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 1) <> "" And bFound = False

    If Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 11) = Sheets("Data2").Cells(iRow, 1) Then
        bFound = True
    End If

    iRow = iRow + 1
Wend
```

Explanation:

```
While Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 1) <> "" And bFound = False
```

will allow the loop to carry on only while we still have data to process AND we still haven't changed `bFound`, which has initial value of `False`.

---

Another option is to use the breakable form of While in VBS:

```
Do While Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""

    If Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 11) = Sheets("Data2").Cells(iRow, 1) Then Exit Do

    iRow = iRow + 1

Loop
```